# How can I connect wooden post and beam inside a 2x4 wall?

Tags: basement, beam, post, support

I'm thinking of framing and drywalling along this beam, but there are 2x4s nailed on the sides of the posts.

I'm thinking of replacing those with appropriate metal hardware. Would that be something like [LCE4](https://www.strongtie.com/miscconnectors_coldformedsteelconstruction/lce_cap/p/lce) or [ACE4](https://www.strongtie.com/twopiecepostcaps_postcaps/ac_cap/p/ac)?

On one hand, I don't want to do anything that's not up to code. But on the other hand, what's there right now doesn't seem like it's a good idea already.

[image: 2x4 connection]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! There's a 2nd 2x4 on the other side. But even with that, it doesn't seem great compared to the hardware that braces in both lateral directions.